# How make object for POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make especial javascript object for AJAX request from `<ul></ul>`. I hope for your help

My particul worked code

link to JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mbarinov/Qwd6T/19/

```
    $('button').click(function() {
    var info = new Object();
    var client = $(this).parent().find("ul li").each(function(index) {
        var name = $(this).attr("rel");
        var value = $(this).text().trim();
        info.Order = {
            name : value
        };
        console.log(info);
    });
});
```

list

```
<ul>
    <li rel="address">address</li>
    <li rel="phone">phone</li>
    <li rel="name">name</li>
    <li rel="summ">summ</li>
    <li rel="description">description</li>
</ul>
```

necessary post request

```
Array
(
    [Order] => Array
        (
            [address] => address
            [phone] => phone
            [name] => name
            [summ] => summ
            [description] => description
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var info = { Order: {} };
    $(this).parent().find("ul li").each(function(index) {
        var name = $(this).attr("rel");
        var value = $(this).text().trim();
        info.Order[name] = value;
        console.log(info);
    });
});
```

Comment: `info.Order = {
            name : value
        };` is not going to work. For all the li elements it will have key and `name`, it will not be the `rel` attribute which OP is looking for.

Comment: The question say "How `make object` for POST request"

Answer (score 0):

You should stringify your object using this library - http://www.json.org/js.html ,
than you post it via this jQuery method - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ .